# how am i getting this output? i dont understand

Tags: java, inheritance, static

```
class ClassOne
{
     static int i, j = 191919;
 
     {
         --i;
     }
 
     {
         j++;
     }
}
```

```
public class ClassTwo extends ClassOne
{
    static
    {
        i++;
    }
 
    static
    {
        --j;
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
 
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

I got the output as

```
i=1
j=191918
```

Comment: You get that output because j is initialized to 191919 and then decremented once, i is initialized to 0 and incremented once. What is there not to understand?

Comment: Note that the code blocks in the class `ClassOne` (`{ --i; }` and `{ j++; }`) are [instance initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) and are only executed when you create a `new ClassOne()` instance.

Comment: Interesting topic, great question.

Answer (score 0):

`static int i, j = 191919;` only initializes `j` to 191919. `i` is initalized to the default, 0.

Answer (score 0):

First, *ClassOne* is created statically, assigning *j* with *191919*.
Then, *ClassTwo* is created statically, which then executes the *static initialization blocks*, incrementing *i* by 1, and subsequently, decrementing *j* by 1.

Your values are now, *1* and *191918*, respectively.

I believe your discrepancy lies within the *instance initialization blocks*, within *ClassTwo*.
*[Initializing Fields (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)*.

These are only executed upon a new instance, and not upon the *static* initialization.